# Best way to remove wrong tags from string

Tags: php, regex

Whats the best way to remove wrong tag?

Tag is wrong if it is contained within the same tag

For example, this line

```
<q>+7</q> (<q><q>9</q>6</q><q>2</q>) <q>9</q><q>3</q><q>7</q> <q>4</q><q>2 2</q><q>4</q>
```

After remove wrong tags:

```
<q>7</q> (<q>96</q><q>2</q>) <q>9</q><q>3</q><q>7</q> <q>4</q><q>2 2</q><q>4</q>
```

More than this simple example:

Before:

```
<p>bla-bla <p>bla-bla</p> bla-bla</p>
```

After:

```
<p>bla-bla bla-bla bla-bla</p>
```

Comment: You should probably give http://htmlpurifier.org/ a try.

Comment: You should use an XML parser (in PHP you have [DOMDocument](http://php.net/dom)) if by *wrong* you mean *wrong according to the X/HTML spec*.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth any compliant XML parser will accept those tags. It just won't do with it what you expect, because languages like HTML are promiscuous by design. According to the spec, `<p>foo <p>bar</p> baz</p>` will just result in `<p>foo </p><p>bar</p><p> baz</p>`. It assumes that what you *meant* to do was close the first paragraph tag before opening a new one. So it does for you implicitly.

Comment: I just want to remove the tags that are contained within the same tag. Without big libs and parsers. i thinnk about regexp, but 
my attempts are unsuccessful

Comment: Meaning... **No compliant HTML parser can assume any different**.

Comment: Yea, you're trying to parse X/HTML with the restriction of not using an X/HTML parser. Good luck with that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

This question pretty much covers everything you need to know:  [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

The long and short of it:  You don't use regex for this.  You "could" but it would be so complex that it would create issues elsewhere in your code.   Either trim your codebase, run an html purifier, an xml parser, or something else along those lines. Regex is likely the wrong solution for your issue.

Comment: If you think this question is a duplicate, simply flag it as such. Posting a link to the other question as an answer just adds clutter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this pattern:

```
(<(.+)>)(.+?)(<\2>)(.*?)(<\/\2>)(.*?)(<\/\2>)$
```

and replace your string for

```
$1$3$5$7$8
```

I believe that you can do like this on PHP

```
   echo preg_replace("(<(.+)>)(.+?)(<\\2>)(.*?)(<\\/\\2>)(.*?)(<\\/\\2>)$", "$1$3$5$7$8", "<p>bla-bla <p>bla-bla</p> bla-bla</p>");
```

you can see a live example of this regex working here http://regexr.com/3e8o3

An important remark is that you may need to call this in a while loop until the regex stop matching, because this regex is not recursive, so this will not work for 3 or more levels of nesting.